# How do I determine which cookies are being blocked by Chrome 80

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, privacy-policy

I currently am using Chrome 79 with the flags enabled to emulate the upcoming feature in Chrome 80

```
chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies
chrome://flags/#cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure
```

When I visit a site with my Developer Tools open and review the console logs, all it says is that it blocked a cookie, with no idication WHAT cookie it blocked.

**How do I determine what cookie was blocked?**

Answer (score 1):

Try it in Chrome Canary.  You still have to manually enable the flags for some reason (despite Canary being Chrome 81 at this point), but you have the option to only show blocked cookies, which provide you with a lot more information.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome DevTools, inside Network panel, enable the **Has blocked cookies** option to only show requests with blocked response cookies.